# Using Appium, How to run Chrome browser in an emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, appium

Appium Version : 1.0.0

```
DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();

cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"emulator-5554");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"Chrome");
cap.setCapability("apppackage","com.anroid.chrome");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT,"100");

AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver=new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
```

Answer (score 0):

This configuration works for me: *Appium server 1.7.1*, *java-client 5.0.4*

```
DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();

cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"emulator-5554");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, MobileBrowserType.BROWSER);

AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<>(
            new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
```

In this case, default browser will be used. If you want chrome, make sure it is **pre-installed on emulator**
If it is, you may use `MobileBrowserType.CHROME`